# How do socket.io implements the authorization

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I want to set the Authorization header in my websocket request to send a token.

I have found no native ways to do so (I settled for passing a token in the query parameters). I see that socket.io provides this functionality (altough I have not tryed it) and I'm wondering how it works under the hood

Answer (score 0):

As a work around I use express-session, with express-socket.io-session (https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session)

This way I found it is easy to set an identifier when a user logs in.

p.s. all the methods in express-session docs, are available to you in express-socket.io-session.